# linking OpenMP statically with GCC

Tags: gcc, openmp, static-linking

Given the following file print.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    printf("asdf\n");
}
```

I can link this statically like this

```
g++ -static print.cpp
```

or like this

```
g++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lc print.cpp -o print
```

But now let's add a little OpenMP and call the file print_omp.cpp

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    printf("%d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

I can link this statically like this (I checked it with `ldd`)

```
g++ -fopenmp -static print_omp.cpp
```

However, this does not work

```
g++ -fopenmp -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lc print_omp.cpp -o print
```

I have tried various combinations of [-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/OpenMP.html) and -lgomp -lpthread but no luck (I get various problems linking to pthreads).  Can someone explain how I can do this without using the `-static` option?

[GCC says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/OpenMP.html)

> On glibc-based systems, OpenMP enabled applications cannot be statically linked due to limitations of the underlying pthreads-implementation

However, since `g++ -fopenmp -static print_omp.cpp` works just fine this does not make sense to me.

Edit:
**I figured this out.** The library GOMP comes with GCC whereas pthreads and libc come from GLIBC. So I can link GOMP statically like this

```
ln -s `g++ -print-file-name=libgomp.a`
g++ foo.cpp -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L. -o foo -O3 -fopenmp
```

ldd shows

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff71dbe000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc231923000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc23155c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc231b5c000)
```

However, if I the try this

```
ln -s `g++ -print-file-name=libpthread.a`
g++ foo.cpp -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L. -o foo -O3 -fopenmp
```

It won't link. **Pthreads and libc must be linked statically together.**  So once I add

```
ln -s `g++ -print-file-name=libc.a`
g++ foo.cpp -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L. -o foo -O3 -fopenmp
```

ldd returns

```
not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: `libgcc` is not everything, `libgomp` is not part of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't get why you may want to link only `libgomp` statically, but having separate compilation and linking commands may help. For instance assume `main.cpp` contains:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
#pragma omp parallel
  {
    printf("%d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
  }
}
```

Then:

```
~/tmp$ ls
main.cpp
~/tmp$ g++  -Wall -Werror -pedantic  -fopenmp main.cpp  -c
~/tmp$ ls
main.cpp  main.o
~/tmp$ locate libgomp.a
${SOME_PATH_TO_LIBGOMP}/libgomp.a
~/tmp$ g++  -Wall -Werror -pedantic main.o -o main.x ${SOME_PATH_TO_LIBGOMP}/libgomp.a -pthread
~/tmp$ ls
main.cpp  main.o  main.x
~/tmp$ ldd main.x
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7747000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /production/install/gnu/compiler/gcc/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb765c000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb75fa000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /production/install/gnu/compiler/gcc/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb75de000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb75c2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7413000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7748000)
```

Comment: That looks reasonable.  I'll check it out tomorrow.  Basically I'm making a shared library on Linux and Windows.  The other developers want as few dependencies as possible.  I recently tested my library on a NUMA system with an older version of Linux and it aborted due to some missing version of a library.  So now I'm trying to remove dependencies. Surprisingly, this was easy with MSVC (except for OpenMP which can't be linked statically, except on the Xbox).  But so far it's been far more of a pain on Linux than I expected.

Answer (score 2):

The most clean solution I've found for this is by modifying the `libgomp.spec`. Mine is at `/usr/local/lib64/libgomp.spec`. Change the content as follow:

```
*link_gomp: -l:libgomp.a %{static: -ldl }
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this is the most clean solution?