# How to link libgomp statically when linking other libraries dynamically?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, openmp, static-linking

I am trying to build an image processing program written in C++ that depends on the following libraries using MinGW + MSYS (with GCC4.8.1) that I downloaded from www.mingw.org/ on a Windows 8 64bit computer

> LibJPEG
>
> BLAS and LAPACK
>
> Armadillo
>
> OpenMP

I have successfully compiled all the source code files (with -fopenmp flag of course), then I linked with the following statement:

> g++ -o ./build/rspfitter  {a list of .o files}
>   -L{paths to libraries}  -ljpeg  -lopenblas -lgomp -lpthread

The executable was correctly produced. However, it asks for the following dlls:

> libgomp-1.dll
>
> libpthread-2.dll
>
> pthreadGC2.dll

I think it might a better idea to link libgomp and libpthread statically, so that I can minimize the number of dlls I need to deploy my program with (the above three dlls are not the only ones the program depends on). So I tried to link only libgomp and libpthread statically with the following command:

> g++ -o ./build/rspfitter  {a list of .o files}
>   -L{paths to libraries}  -ljpeg  -lopenblas -Wl,-static  -lgomp  -lpthread

But this time it fails with the following error message:

> d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1\libgomp.a(env.o):(.text.startup+0xbfe):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_attr_init'
>
> d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1\libgomp.a(env.o):(.text.startup+0xc13):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_attr_setdetachstate'
>
> d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1\libgomp.a(env.o):(.text.startup+0x3c):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_attr_setstacksize'
>
> d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>
> d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1\libgomp.a(env.o): bad reloc
>   address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
>
> d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>
> final link failed: Invalid operation

Then I tried to execute the exact same compiling and linking commands using the MinGW + GCC 4.8.1 environment that was installed together with CodeLite. It fails again with different error messages：

> ./tmp/hshfitcmdline.o:hshfitcmdline.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x105):
>   undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
>
> ./tmp/hshfitcmdline.o:hshfitcmdline.cpp:(.text$_ZN9NormalMapD1Ev[__ZN9NormalMapD1Ev]+0xb4):
>   undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
>
> d:/mingw-4.8.1/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>
> ./tmp/hshfitcmdline.o: bad reloc address 0xb4 in section
>   `.text$_ZN9NormalMapD1Ev[__ZN9NormalMapD1Ev]'
>
> d:/mingw-4.8.1/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>
> final link failed: Invalid operation collect2.exe: error: ld returned
>
> 1 exit status make: *** [build/rspfitter] Error 1

I confirmed that the file "libgomp.a"/"libgomp.dll.a" was present on the [MinGW dir]/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/ for both installations of MinGW. However, they are of different sizes! In installation downloaded from MinGW.org, 'libgomp.a' is of 86kb, and "libgomp.dll.a" is of 87kb; In the CodeLite installation, however, the sizes are 74kB and 148Kb respectively.

Now I am wondering:

1. What could be the cause of the error messages given by the two MinGW systems? Could it be that the statically libraries that I downloaded from MinGW are corrputed? But dynamically linking was perfectly fine on both systems.
2. How on earth can I correctly link libgomp statically?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869981/linking-openmp-statically-with-gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To link libgomp statically you can do

```
ln -s `g++ --print-file-name=libgomp.a` && \
g++ foo.o -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L. -o foo -fopenmp -ljpeg -lopenblas
```

However your executable will still depend on a pthread dll. The reason you are getting the error is that `libc` is still linking dynamically. To fix this you have to link `libc` statically as well

```
ln -s `g++ --print-file-name=libpthread.a` && \
ln -s `g++ --print-file-name=libc.a` && \
g++ foo.o -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L. -o foo -fopenmp -ljpeg -lopenblas
```

However, if `openblas` or `jpeg` libraries depend on `libc` then there will likely still be undefined references.

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem was solved. Sorry for the delayed acceptance.

Comment: @MingjingZhang, it worked! That's good to know. I gave up with static linking on Linux but it still seems okay on Windows.

Comment: @Boson, sorry I have to update my response. What I observed was the size of the executable increases from 1.19MB to around 1.4MB, and it runs without dlls in the same folder, so I thought it worked. It wasn't until just now did I realize I added the path to the dlls as an environment variable at some point and the exec actually invoked the dlls there. If I remove the variable, it still reports a missing dll error. The increased size could be due to -static-libstdc++. Anyway, my supervisor thought it is okay to release it with dlls; guess I can skip this prob for now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MingjingZhang, next time use Dependency Walker to find the DLLs it depends on.