# Linking openMP statically

Tags: gcc, linker, openmp, static-linking

I have a cpp file with openMP functions and I want to link it statically. I have already tried solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869981/linking-openmp-statically-with-gcc) but without success.

If I use the following commands:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -fopenmp -o main.o
g++ -static -lgomp -lpthread main.o -o main
```

I get errors saying that there is no reference to "dlopen, dlsym, dlclose, dlerror".

So, I tried also to add `-fopenmp` flag in linking command:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -fopenmp -o main.o
g++ -static -lgomp -lpthread -fopenmp main.o -o main
```

Now I don't receive linking errors, but I get this warning:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgomp.a(target.o): in function "gomp_target_init":
(.text+0x8b): attention: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

This warning suggest me that **static linking** has not been successful (even if `ldd main` states `is not a dynamic executable`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This message is just a warning, not an error. do `ldd main` and you should get `not a dynamic executable`

Comment: @Gilles thanks for your response. My problem is that I have to run the binary with a simulator [gem5](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/) in which it is not possible to have dynamic linking. That warning it is okay if I execute the application in my Ubuntu OS, but it can be ignored if I have to run the application on that simulator.

Comment: just try it. It is very likely it will work, although it is not guaranteed. You'll know immediately anyway.