# libgomp_64-1.dll problem when using Dev C++

Tags: c, dll, parallel-processing

I'm working on a piece of code using Dev C++ and C language. I need to make it run parallel, so I just added `<omp.h>` header and provided `-fopenmp` flag to the compiler. the program perfectly runs when run from Dev C++ directly, but it fails to run when standalone `*.exe` is executed. In that case, it reports that `libgomp_64-1.dll` was not found.

here is a linked command as I can see it:

```
    Processing C source file...
--------
- C Compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe
- Command: gcc.exe "C:\Users\jan.kubacka\OneDrive - GA Drilling\Documents\vypocty\Tl_new_model_Lee\feasibility study\znamzat\TH-DBHE_v02.c" -o "C:\Users\jan.kubacka\OneDrive - GA Drilling\Documents\vypocty\Tl_new_model_Lee\feasibility study\znamzat\TH-DBHE_v02.exe" -fopenmp -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -static-libgcc
```

I did check the directory for binaries and the folder where `libgomp_64-1.dll` is stored is linked correctly. I suppose when I include `libgomp_64-1.dll` into the folder where `*.exe` is stored it would work, but this is not what I want. I was kind of hoping that the produced `*.exe` will work without any need for any auxiliary files. In addition to this, when I pass the `*.exe` file to somebody who does not have the Dev C++ installed (and hence his PC has no `libgomp_64-1.dll` in it), does this mean that it will simply not work? I always thought that when a `.exe` file is compiled, it stores all necessary data to be executed anywhere. Am I wrong with this?

Many thanks for the clarification.

j.

Comment: You seem to want to link a static library instead of a shared llibrary. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the full linker command that gets executed when you build the application.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Here is the linked command (at least I hope so): - C Compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe
- Command: gcc.exe "C:\Users\****\TH-DBHE_v02.c" -o "C:\Users\****\TH-DBHE_v02.exe" -fopenmp -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -static-libgcc

Comment: Please don't use comments to provide requested information, [edit] your question instead. Make sure to copy&paste everything as re-typing might introduce or hide errors. Use code block formatting, e.g by using the `{}` tool of the editor field or by inserting 3 backticks or 3 tilde characters (`~~~`) as separate lines before and after the code.

Comment: Hi Bodo, question updated, thank you. Any idea how to make it work? Response much appreciated!

Comment: Answers to this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23869981/10622916